# ErrorHandlingDeserializer for older version of spring-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a very old version of Kafka and want to implement something like an ErrorHandlingDeserializer which is not available out of the box. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` and `FailedDeserializationInfo` classes from current Spring for Apache Kafka version into your project and use them respectively: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#error-handling-deserializer

But, of course, it depends how old is your solution. Kafka headers abstraction is not available in very old one. So, you might need to adjust that class to not deal with headers.